# Netty Custom DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder

Tags: java, netty

My company is exploring the possibility of using the Netty Framework to implement a message router.  The messages that it will be routing come from many different sources and all have their own formats.  In most cases the messages are in XML which includes a header that contains the body length. However we have one vendor who's message are different and don't contain the length of the body.

This one vendors message contains a HEADER, BODY and TRAILER.
The header is 1 byte and is an STX (0x02)
The body is variable length
The trailer is 2 bytes which contain an ETX(0x03) followed by an LRC.

So a typical message might look like:

```
STX   BODY   ETX  LRC
02  37000000 06   18
```

We initially used the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder defining the ETX as the delimiter, however when we do that we lose the LRC byte that is part of the message. As a result, the LRC ends up being the first byte of the next message that we decode. Is there a way to use the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder and read one byte past the ETX delimiter?

Further, when we send a response back to the source, the source will then send us an ACK which we have to respond to with an ACK as well.

I am thinking that we need a custom decoder that reads the byte, if it is an ACK then it notifies the next handler, otherwise, it continues reading until it reads 1 byte past the ETX and then sends that message on to the next handler.  Does that seem reasonable?  Is there a better way or is there a decoder in Netty that I might want to use instead of of the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder?

Any help that I can get on this is appreciated!

## UPDATE

So at Norman's suggestion, I created the following decoder:

```
public class MyDecoder extends DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder{

    public MyDecoder(int maxFrameLength, boolean stripDelimiter, ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(maxFrameLength, stripDelimiter, delimiter);
        this.setSingleDecode(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer) throws Exception {
        Object frame = super.decode(ctx, buffer);
        ByteBuf bufFrame = null;
    
    if(frame instanceof ByteBuf){
        bufFrame = (ByteBuf)frame;
        
        }else{
            System.out.println("OBJECT TYPE: " + frame.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    
        byte lrc = buffer.readByte();
        bufFrame.writeByte(lrc);
        return bufFrame;
   }

    public MyDecoder(int maxFrameLength, ByteBuf delimiter) {
        super(maxFrameLength, delimiter);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        super.channelActive(ctx);
        System.out.println("VERIFONE DECODER READY");
    }
}
```

My Handlers are initialized with the following...

```
public class MyChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    ByteBuf delimiter;
    byte[] ETX = {0x03};
    byte[] STX = {0x02};

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        setupDelimiter();
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyDecoder(65*1024, false, delimiter));
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder());
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder());
        ch.pipeline().addLast(new MyHandler());
   }

   private void setupDelimiter(){
       delimiter = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(ETX);
    
   }

}
```

Everything works as expected, I get my full message including the LRC which is the 1 byte after the ETX, however, it throws the following Exception...

```
May 09, 2014 5:11:43 PM io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$TailHandler exceptionCaught
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It
usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:258)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:140)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:74)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:138)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:320)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:127)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:485)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:452)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:346)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:794)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.test.MyDecoder.decode(MyDecoder.java:33)
at     io.netty.handler.codec.DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.decode(DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.java:216)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:227)
... 11 more
```

I am not sure why this is happening...

Any thoughts on what I should be looking at?

Comment: is the LRC byte different or is it the same all the time ?

Comment: The LRC is a computed field that is based on the information in the body. So it is different for each message.

Comment: @milltj did you ever found solution for it? I have to implement the same protocol here. Can you share the code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need your own version of a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder that handles the case. Basically just a copy of the one shipped with Netty but also consume 1 more byte after the delimiter.

Comment: you are right. However, implementation isn't so easy to write. It will be quite different than `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` has.