# Netty message tokenization

Tags: java, netty, tcp

I am working on an application which receives messages formatted as follows

> /This is a received message##

i want to use [Netty](http://netty.io/) to read messages based on start delimiter '/' and end delimiter '##' as a string instead of reading character by character from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html).

**Edit**

When I said "have a look at" I meant using that class as a starting point for extension or creating your own version. Another approach would be to just use one of the delimiters and then strip off the other.

Comment: i saw the above link, but i found that when this class found more than one delimiter it will choose the delimiter which make the shortest frame, also i don't see a direct way to specify start and end delimiter, i found also [Netty Custom DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528826/netty-custom-delimiterbasedframedecoder) but i don't quite understand how he will use start and end delimiter